# Why Menu "Action" showing duplicate options of one window action in Odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have created a menu Under "Actions" which is running fine on local machine server but where i updated this code on server , the new created option showing twice. Please guide me how to resolve

[image]

Comment: How did you add this option? Can you please add your xml code?

Comment: Solved it .. thanks

Comment: Please share the solution ;-)

Comment: What's your solution dear @majid ?